# Como aumentar o tamanho do varchar em MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela e a acesso via MySQL, estou usando este comando para aumentar o `varchar` de 50 para 60:

```
alter table tabela alter column nome varchar(60) not null
```

Mas só recebo como resposta:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

Alguém saberia qual o erro de sintaxe? Já tentei sem o `not null`, com aspas simples no `60`, com e sem ponto e vírgula no final, estou ficando sem ideias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE "nome_tabela" MODIFY "NOME_CAMPO" varchar(60);
```

Lembrando que o nome da tabela e o nome do campo é sem aspas (`""`).